# Bitmap for a three state check box with OBM_CHECKBOXES

Tags: winapi, mfc

I want to use three state checkbox in the list control. Today, there is facility for normal checkbox. The bitmap for normal check box are loaded from `OBM_CHECKBOXES`.

The problem is, I am not able to find the bitmap image for intermediate state (`CBS_MIXEDNORMAL`). Could anyone help which image index I can use for intermediate state using `OBM_CHECKBOXES`.

Comment: How do you load the bitmaps?

Answer (score 0):

That is a non-themed bitmap. If you want a themed bitmap, you have to use the [`DrawThemeBackground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-drawthemebackground) to draw it to create a bitmap.

There are two bitmaps may be used for intermediate state:

One is `CBS_MIXEDNORMAL`. `DrawThemeBackground(theme, hdc, BP_CHECKBOX, CBS_MIXEDNORMAL, &rc, nullptr);`

[image]

Another is `CBS_CHECKEDDISABLED`. `DrawThemeBackground(theme, hdc, BP_CHECKBOX, CBS_CHECKEDDISABLED, &rc, nullptr);`

[image]

Code sample as below:

```
 HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
 HTHEME theme = OpenThemeData(nullptr, L"Button");
    
 RECT rc = {};
 rc.right = 12;
 rc.bottom = 12;
 DrawThemeBackground(theme, hdc, BP_CHECKBOX, CBS_MIXEDNORMAL, &rc, nullptr);
    
 CloseThemeData(theme);
    
 EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```